# Android - latest open source 3d libraries for android

Tags: android, opengl-es, 3d, 3d-engine

Im currently looking at using min3d but came across a thread where the original creator said he was moving on and it wasnt going to be supported anymore. I dont think that would be to big of a problem for myself but I was wondering if anyone else had used any 3d libraries with similar functionality as min3d.

Ideally Im looking for something lightweight that mostly handles the opengl and possibly screen touch events on objects.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[libgdx](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/) - very popular and up to date

[jPCT-AE](http://www.jpct.net/jpct-ae/) (fairly recently updated)

[dwarf-fw](http://code.google.com/p/dwarf-fw/) (hasn't been updated in a while)

[catcake](http://code.google.com/p/catcake/) (hasn't been updated in a while)

Also looks like someone ported [irrlicht to Android](http://gitorious.org/irrlichtandroid/pages/Home) if you don't mind using C++ / NDK.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for the links. Ill probably take a look at libgdx as I have seen it mentioned in quite a few places but Ive never really looked at it. Do you have any experience using libgdx? Im just curious about how easy/difficult it is to set up a 3d scene and deal with camera views.

Comment: I haven't used it extensively but the nice thing about it is that you can develop on the desktop and deploy to Android without much extra work. Check out the camera tutorial on the website...they use an orthographic camera, you'd need a perspective one but it seems pretty straightforward: http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/ProjectionViewportCamera

Comment: Very cool :) I was hoping to use it to set up a scene with a transparent background so I can have 3d images drawn over a camera view from the android hardware camera.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a list of all popular Android libraries:
http://www.appbrain.com/stats/libraries/dev

libgdx is very popular and also AndEngine and Unity 3d