# Android: code for 3D human body that can be animated

Tags: java, android, graphics

I'm looking for something rather specific here. It'd be great if it already exists, if not I don't mind piecing together what's needed.

Essentially: I want to show a 3D human body model on the screen, and in code, be able to manipulate joints to create custom animations; nothing too facny though. Just something along the lines of `leftElbowJoint.rotate(57)` would be perfect.

Any recommended code and/or starting points?

Comment: Consider looking at existing 3D game engines as they already have properties for 'bones' and articulation for character models.

Comment: Do you know of any for Android that could suit my purposes? Good suggestion on the game engines.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use 3D objects in your Application or Wallpapers. Take a look at [RajaWali](https://github.com/MasDennis/Rajawali) Library which is based on OpenGL ES 2.0/3.0. Download the library and Demo App where he use good 3D Animations on Blender objects. Like Crawling , Hand moving. One of his Animation Example  is [here](https://github.com/MasDennis/Rajawali/wiki/Tutorial-29-Skeletal-Animation).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how advanced your programming experience is. But here are a couple of options how you could achieve this:

1) Start from scratch. Have a look at the OpenGL ES library for Android. You would code the basis of your application.

2)  Have a look at a [3d library build on top of OpenGL ES](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9450308/android-latest-open-source-3d-libraries-for-android), that will should reduce the amount of coding need. You would be getting the basis for your application.

3) Have a look at [unity](http://unity3d.com/). Animating 3d objects can be done with ease.

The 3d object human you could either make yourself with an app like [Blender](http://www.blender.org/) or download from a website [like](http://www.blender-models.com/).

Comment: From scratch isn't an option, don't have that much time to invest. Will check out using some of the 3D libraries you mentioned.